# du command not giving accurate results

Tags: terminal, command, size, directory, du

When I try to use `du` command, to see the size of my folders like this for
example:

`du -H --max-depth=1 some-folder/`

```
28M
11M
8.0K
4.2M
260K
896K
86M
7.9M
24K
8.6M
22M
14M
6.0M
60K
912K

365M    total
```

,final size does not shows the real sum of the above numbers. Why the summary size is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The command you're executing shows the folders only.
Therefore any files in `some-folder` only added to the total but not listed individually.
Try this:

```
du -Hs some-folder/*
```

But note that if you have hidden files (ie. files with a dot prefix) won't be listed with this command either.